# InAppBrowser not load the page with cookies when I use the hardware back button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor, inappbrowser

I have an application in Ionic/Angular in which I use the InAppBrowser plugin to use a web application of my company.

The InAppBrowser works fine in general, the situation is that there is a cookie in the web application that is used for the filters of some lists that are in the web application. When a user filters and enters (for example) a specific client from a list and uses the hardware back button to go back, the filter disappears. From the PC, when you go back the filter is maintained, which means that the cache is maintained.

When I use the DevTools (from Google Chrome: chrome://inspect) to check the Ionic app, the cookie works, but when I don't use it, it doesn't work as I mentioned above. It seems that by doing the hardware back button in the InAppBrowser the cache is not maintained or it is not loaded. All this without changing anything in the code.

This is how I create the InAppBrowser:

```
browser = this.iab.create(pageContentUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no,fullscreen=no,clearcache=no,clearsessioncache=no,hidden=yes,toolbar=no');
```

So I'm asking if there is a way that when I do the hardware back button it loads the previous page with the cookie/cache loaded. Or if it really shouldn't load anything since the filter has already been applied and the cookie has been overwritten.

I have tried setting the clearcache and clearsessioncache to 'no' and it doesn't seem to have any effect. And checking with the DevTools inspector everything works fine, but when I don't use it it doesn't work, it's like with DevTools it caches everything but when I don't use it it doesn't work as I expect.

What I expect to happen is that when, for example, a user has used a filter from the web application, when the hardware back button is made, that filter (saved in the cookie) is maintained, just as it does when using the web application. on a PC. What happens right now is that when using the hardware back button the filter that had been made disappears, but the thing is that the cookie still exists, since using the DevTools it works without having made any changes to the code.

Thank you very much in advance.

My Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1 (C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.2.1
   @angular/cli                  : 14.2.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 4.1.0
   @capacitor/android : 4.1.0
   @capacitor/core    : 4.1.0
   @capacitor/ios     : 4.1.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.6.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 8.11.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

**Update**

When the user has used the filter and when using the hardware back button the cookie/cache is not loaded correctly, I have closed the app and I have tried again to perform the same steps of the use case and everything works fine, it is more , the page that has the list is already loaded with the filter by the cookie. So it looks like it fails the first time it's tried, so the failure is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to allow cache and cookies using enabling JAVA script in webview.
Use this :

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Also override the back button of activity to use it as back button on webview :

```
if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly should I put that code? Inside the file where I create the InAppBrowser in Ionic or in a specific file inside Android Studio? I use Ionic 6 and Angular 14, I'll update the question with the ionic info if it's necessary

Comment: you need to put this code in android specific folder under android main file

Comment: Okay I've tested it (put it in the MainActivity under onCreate) and doesn't fix the issue for me sadly